# Update multidimensional array from (Y-m) to (Y)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to know if there is any way to change or update a multidimensional array from this

```
Array ( 
       [AZ] => Array ( [1] => 2020-01 [2] => 2020-02 ) 
       [BY] => Array ( [0] => 2020-03 [1] => 2020-04 ) 
       [CX] => Array ( [1] => 2020-05 [2] => 2020-06 [3] => 2020-07 ) 
       [DW] => Array ( [106] => 2019-01 [107] => 2019-02 [108] => 2019-03)
      )
```

To this

```
Array ( 
       [AZ] => Array ( [1] => 2020 [2] => 2020 ) 
       [BY] => Array ( [0] => 2020 [1] => 2020 ) 
       [CX] => Array ( [1] => 2020 [2] => 2020 [3] => 2020 ) 
       [DW] => Array ( [106] => 2019 [107] => 2019 [108] => 2019)
      )
```

I don't know if this is possible but I hope someone can help me

Comment: Is there anything you've tried? Can you at least change `"2020-01"` to `"2020"`?

Comment: I think something can be done using [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array_walk_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive) to walk over all the values in the array, changing those that match a `YYYY-MM` format to `YYYY` using [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace):

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$v) {
    $v = preg_replace('/^(\d{4})-\d\d$/', '$1', $v);
});
```

Note we use `&$v` as the argument to the callback so that we can change the values in the array.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [AZ] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2020
            [2] => 2020
        )
    [BY] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2020
            [1] => 2020
        )
    [CX] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2020
            [2] => 2020
            [3] => 2020
        )
    [DW] => Array
        (
            [106] => 2019
            [107] => 2019
            [108] => 2019
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/E5Neh)